# Database(3300): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: But the tables name is inspection?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert data into a table that is part of a larger project.  I am getting the error above and cannot figure out how to create the table. The code that created the table is below and the tables name is inspections.  So I very confused.

Here is the logcat info

```
 02-27 18:38:45.956: I/Database(3559): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table:       inspections
 02-27 18:38:45.967: E/Database(3559): Error inserting co_driver= driver=ewrre vehicle_id=ET 432 status=1 date_time=40 vehicle_type=truck
 02-27 18:38:45.967: E/Database(3559): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: inspections: , while compiling: INSERT INTO inspections(co_driver, driver, vehicle_id, status, date_time, vehicle_type) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
02-27 18:38:45.967: E/Database(3559):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
```

Here is the code that creates the table

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table inspections ("
    + "_id integer  primary key autoincrement, "
    + "vehicle_id   string  not null, "
    + "vehicle_type string  not null, "
    + "datetime     integer not null, "
    + "driver       string  not null, "
    + "codriver     string  , "
    + "status       integer not null "
    + ");";

public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(InspectionsTable.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inspections");
    onCreate(database);
}
```

This is the DBhelper class

```
   public class SignalSetDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public SignalSetDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Method is called during creation of the database
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    CurrentStateTable.onCreate(db);
    HoursOfServiceTable.onCreate(db);
    InspectionsTable.onCreate(db);
    }

// Method is called during an upgrade of the database,
// e.g. if you increase the database version
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    CurrentStateTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
    HoursOfServiceTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
}
 }
```

This is the adapter class

```
 public class InspectionDBAdapter {
private static final String KEY_ROWID ="_id";
private static final String KEY_VEHICLE_ID="vehicle_id";
private static final String KEY_VEHICLE_TYPE="vehicle_type";    
private static final String KEY_DATETIME="date_time";
private static final String KEY_DRIVER="driver";
private static final String KEY_CO_DRIVER="co_driver";  
private static final String KEY_STATUS="status";
private static final String DB_TABLE="inspections";
private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private SignalSetDBHelper dbHelper;

public InspectionDBAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public InspectionDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new SignalSetDBHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

public void insertInspection( String vehicle_id, String vehicle_type, 
        int datetime, String driver, String codriver, int status)
{

    ContentValues newContact= createContentValue(vehicle_id, vehicle_type, 
         datetime,  driver, codriver,  status);

    db.insert(DB_TABLE, KEY_STATUS, newContact);

}

private static ContentValues createContentValue(String vehicle_id, String vehicle_type, 
        int datetime, String driver, String codriver, int status)
{
    ContentValues newContact= new ContentValues();
    newContact.put(KEY_VEHICLE_ID  , vehicle_id);
    newContact.put(KEY_VEHICLE_TYPE , vehicle_type);
    newContact.put(KEY_DATETIME  , datetime);
    newContact.put(KEY_DRIVER  , driver);
    newContact.put(KEY_CO_DRIVER , codriver);
    newContact.put(KEY_STATUS  , status);

    return newContact;
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are creating the table inspections?

Comment: I just added the code that created the table.  The table name is inspections, so this is why I am confused.  The class name is InspectionTable.  I tried that and it did not work

Comment: Can you please post complete code of the class where you create table.I think,you have extended SQLiteOpenHelper class in that.

Comment: If you made changes recently to the Database structure (table definitions etc) then you have to increment the value of database version variable.

Comment: @Hiral I posted the code with the SQLiteOpenHelper and the adapter class.

Comment: @Yaqub I did not make any changes to the DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making your SignalSetDBHelper class like:

```
public class SignalSetDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String INSPECTION_CREATE = "create table inspections ("
    + "_id integer  primary key autoincrement, "
    + "vehicle_id   string  not null, "
    + "vehicle_type string  not null, "
    + "datetime     integer not null, "
    + "driver       string  not null, "
    + "codriver     string  , "
    + "status       integer not null "
    + ");";

    public SignalSetDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }       
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        database.execSQL(INSPECTION_CREATE); 
        //do same for other two tables
    }            
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inspections");
        // do same for other two tables
        onCreate(database);        
    }
}
```

And in your code of SignalSetDBHelper class,in onUpgrade method,you didn't include InspectionsTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion); and after all statements,you should also add onCreate(database); there.So try adding this to your existing code and see the result for any success you would get!